# How can I fix snap run on non-Ubuntu Linux kernel 4.18?

Tags: linux-kernel, snap, pureos

I'm running snap applications on a non-Ubuntu system:

```
$ snap version                                                                                                                                   
snap    2.30-5+b1
snapd   2.30-5+b1
series  16
pureos  
kernel  4.18.0-1-amd64
```

When I `snap run` some applications work, but others return this error:

```
cannot perform readlinkat() on the mount namespace file descriptor of the init process: Permission denied
```

Following [suggestions at snapcraft.io](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/custom-kernel-error-on-readlinkat-in-mount-namespace/6097/33), I have tried:

- Switching to the beta core. Same error.
- Modifying the AppArmor profile as follows:

  1. Running `snap list` to identify exactly which revision of core I'm using (core 16-2.35.2 r 5548)
  2. Modifying the appropriate file (`/etc/apparmor.d/snap.core.5548.usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine`) by adding `ptrace read peer=unconfined,` to the end as described.
  3. Updating AppArmor with `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/snap.core.5548.usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine`

But this makes no difference. The failing applications continue to fail. What else can I do?

---

**Notes**

Confirmed step 2 with:

```
$ tail /etc/apparmor.d/snap.core.5548.usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine                                                                                 
    # from the core snap but we are already inside the constructed mount
    # namespace. Here the apparmor kernel module re-constructs the path to
    # snap-update-ns using the "hostfs" mount entry rather than the more
    # "natural" /snap mount entry but we have no control over that.  This is
    # reported as (LP: #1716339). The variants here represent different
    # locations of snap mount directory across distributions.
    /var/lib/snapd/hostfs/{,var/lib/snapd/}snap/core/*/usr/lib/snapd/snap-update-ns r,

    ptrace read peer=unconfined,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the following additional changes resolved the issue. These steps [didn't work for another user on the snapcraft thread](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/custom-kernel-error-on-readlinkat-in-mount-namespace/6097/32), but they did work for me. I'm not sure if any of the previous changes are in fact unnecessary.

1. Modify `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real` by adding `ptrace read peer=unconfined,` at the end, as follows:

   ```
   $ tail /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real                                                                                       
           # But we don't want anyone to touch /snap/bin
           audit deny mount /snap/bin/** -> /**,
           audit deny mount /** -> /snap/bin/**,

           # Allow the content interface to bind fonts from the host filesystem
           mount options=(ro bind) /var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/fonts/ -> /snap/*/*/**,
       }

       ptrace read peer=unconfined,
   }
   ```
2. `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*`